# Problems with split(String regex)

Tags: java, regex, string, exception, split

Hi I'm having issues with the code below (file is of the File class):

```
String[] fileNameSplit = file.getName().split(".");
String fileType = fileNameSplit[(fileNameSplit.length - 1)];
```

It always throws a ArrayOutOfBoundsExecption at -1 suggesting that fileNameSplit is 0. When I take out the -1 it still says ArrayOutOfBoundsException but now at 0, meaning it is empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `.` is a [*meta-character*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) that accepts "any character". It treats every single character of your string as a delimiter, "eating up" its entire content.

Escape the dot it like this:

```
String[] fileNameSplit = file.getName().split("\\.");
```

or use a character class, like this:

```
String[] fileNameSplit = file.getName().split("[.]");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `\\.`

`String[] fileNameSplit = file.getName().split("\\.");`

As `regex` and `String` don't go well with each other, 1st `\` is needed to be used to make the compiler realize that its not a `dot(.)` but a regex, and 2nd `\` to make the java compiler take `\` as literally.

Comment: Yes sorry you were but I'm using the "[.]" way rather than the "\\." way so I thought I would give credit where it was due... When my rep is high enough I will upvote up though

Comment: @AqueousSnake no its perfectly fine.. No need to upvote it any further... but please mention you needs before hand, so you can get the apt answer.... `\\.` is the most common way of doing it..so i mentioned it...  well whats done is done... fine... but thanks for that upvote...

Answer (score 1):

Note that the argument to the `split` method is a regex. In the regex, the dot has a special meaning: match *any* character.

To use the dot *literally*, you'll need to escape it:

```
`String[] fileNameSplit = file.getName().split("\\.");`
```

[docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) for the `split` method.